# ¿Como guardar los elementos que se añaden dentro de un hilo?

Tags: java

aqui mando a llamar a los metodo  primero al metodo agregarNumeros() para qeu la lista tenga numeros y no este vacia luego lo compruebo llamando al metodo imprimirNumeros() ya una ves sabiendo que si se agregaron lso numeros ahora es cuando ejecuto al metodo crearHilos() y despues vuelvo a ejecutar el metodo imprimirNumeros() y me doy cuenta que no se guardan los elementos.

```
public class GenerarNumeroRandombs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        a clase = new a();

        clase.agregarNumeros();
        clase.imprimirNumeros();
        clase.crearHilos();
        System.out.println("-----");
        clase.imprimirNumeros();
    }
}
```

En esta clase creo una Lista de tipo Integer tengo 3 metodos, en agregarNumeros()()aniado elementos a la lista, en imprimirNumeros() los imprimo, y en el otro metodo crearHilos() es donde aniado numeros pero ahora dentro de un hilo.

```
class a {

    ArrayList<Integer> miList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void agregarNumeros() {
        miList.add(2);
        miList.add(2);
        miList.add(2);  
    }

    public void imprimirNumeros() {
        for (int i = 0; i < miList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(miList.get(i));
        } 
    }

    public void crearHilos() {
        Thread hilo = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("sadcsd");
                miList.add(2);
                miList.add(2);
                miList.add(2);
            }
        };

        hilo.start();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Lo que te debe estar pasando es que no esperas a que termine el thread. Llamas a la función crearHilos() que crea el hilo pero no es sincrona, así que lanza el thread y retorna y justo a continuación llamas a imprimir otra vez, pero tal vez el thread ni si quiera haya empezado, o no haya terminado y tu programa termina, con lo que el thread muere tal vez antes incluso de empezar la ejecución. Pon un sleep tras llamar a crearHilos y antes de llamar a imprimir, si entonces le da tiempo a imprimir, el problema será el que te digo y tendrás que sincronizar tu thread con el thread principal.

Comment: tienes razon, es cierto que mientras se ejecuta el hilo se ejecuta otro proceso, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementando interface `Runnable` (más conveniente):

```
package ejemplohilos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EjemploHilos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A clase = new A();

        clase.agregarNumeros();
        clase.imprimirNumeros();
        System.out.println("-----");

        //creamos objeto HiloAgregarElement, que es nuestra clase que implementa Runnable, 
        //pasándole por constructor objeto clase, que es el que tiene la lista
        Runnable hiloAgregElement1 =new HiloAgregarElement(clase);
        //creamos objeto Thread pasándole por constructor el objeto Runnable
        Thread thrAgregElement1=new Thread(hiloAgregElement1);
        thrAgregElement1.start();

        //segundo hilo
        Runnable hiloAgregElement2 =new HiloAgregarElement(clase);
        Thread thrAgregElement2=new Thread(hiloAgregElement2);
        thrAgregElement2.start();
    }    
}
class A{

    List<Integer> miList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void agregarNumeros() {
        miList.add(2);
        miList.add(2);
        miList.add(2);  
    }

    public void imprimirNumeros() {
        for (int i = 0; i < miList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(miList.get(i));
        } 
    }
    //getter para acceder a la lista desde Hilo
    public List<Integer> getMiList() {
        return miList;
    }   
}
class HiloAgregarElement implements Runnable{

    private A objetoA;

    public HiloAgregarElement(A objetoA) {
        this.objetoA =objetoA;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("sadcsd");
        objetoA.getMiList().add(3);
        objetoA.getMiList().add(3);
        objetoA.getMiList().add(3);

        objetoA.imprimirNumeros();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu programa está bien.

Al parecer los número no se guardaron en la lista pero te aseguro que si se están guardando. Como te comenta @SuperG280:

> "...Llamas a la función crearHilos() que crea el hilo pero no es sincrona, así que lanza el thread y retorna y justo a continuación llamas a imprimir otra vez..."

Si lo que quieres es imprimir la lista una vez termine de ejecutarse el `Thread` te recomiendo que agregues una llamada al método `imprimirNumeros()` al final de la ejecución del método `run()` del `Thread`.

```
public void crearHilos() {
    Thread hilo = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("sadcsd");
            miList.add(4);
            miList.add(5);
            miList.add(6);

            imprimirNumeros();
        }
    };

    hilo.start();
}
```

Comment: gracias los dos tienen razon